# scope & trigger in angular1

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Could you point me to the right direction what I should look up in order to understand the following code about `trigger: "=trigger"`

```
app.module.directive('messageModal', function ($compile) {
    return {
        scope: {
            trigger: "=trigger",
        },

        controller: ['$scope', '$element', '$attrs', '$timeout', function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $timeout) {
                $scope.trigger = function(title, message, modal_class, color, auto_hide){
```

What I understand is that by having `scope: {},`  the directive `'messageModal'`has created a brand new scope object. BUT what does `trigger: "=trigger"` do? What about the `$scope.trigger`?

Please I need some directions on what I should learn in order to understand what the directive does. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Properties within `scope` option are mappings between each property and an attribute in the directive markup when you're using it somewhere.

Scope's property value defines how scope properties are bound:

- `=` means two-way binding
- `@` means literal binding.
- `&` means function binding.

A scope property can be provided in two ways (with any of above described bindings):

- `{ some: "=" }` which means that scope property and its HTML attribute counterpart will share the same identifier.
- `{ some: "=whatever" }` allows you to define how will be identified the attribute bound to the whole scope property.

Once an *isolated scope* has already bound properties and attributes, you'll access them injecting `$scope` and accessing the property: `$scope.whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing special about 'trigger', it's just a name of the property you can use to communicate with directive from HTML.

For example, if you use it like this:

```
<messageModal trigger="whatever here"></messageModal>
```

Then inside the directive $scope.trigger is going to be equal to "whatever here".